# Error when adding parenthesis in multiplying int and double in java why?

Tags: java, int, double

This is a working code but I am wondering after a full research on multiplying ints and doubles in Java I still can't see why the snippet below the code would give an error. Any help please?

```
public class Arithmetic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double mealCost = scan.nextDouble(); // original meal price
        int tipPercent = scan.nextInt(); // tip percentage
        int taxPercent = scan.nextInt(); // tax percentage
        scan.close();

        // Calculate Tax and Tip:
        double tip = mealCost * tipPercent / 100; //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
        double tax = mealCost * taxPercent / 100; //HERE IS MY PROBLEM

        // cast the result of the rounding operation to an int and save it as totalCost 
        int totalCost = (int) Math.round(mealCost + tax + tip);

        System.out.println("The total meal cost is " + totalCost + " dollars.");
    }
}
```

Knowing that this answer is more logical and gives a different value than the one above?!

```
double tip = meal * (tipPercent/100);
double tax = meal * (taxPercent/100);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your 1st example, the multiplication is performed first, resulting in a double number that is then divided by 100, giving the correct double result:

```
mealCost * tipPercent / 100;
```

In your 2nd version, an integer division is performed first, resulting in an integer  result. Assuming that `tipPercent` less than 100, the result will be zero.

If you like the second version better, just use a floating point constant:

```
double tip = meal * (tipPercent/100.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine:

```
int tipPercent = 10;
double mealCost = 100.123d;
```

And

```
double tip = mealCost * tipPercent / 100;
```

1. 100.123(`double`) * 10(`int`) = 1001.23(`double`)
2. 1001.23(`double`) / 100(`int`) = 10.0123(`double`)

In the second:

```
double tip = mealCost * (tipPercent / 100);
```

1. 10(`int`) / 100(`int`) = 0(`int`)
2. 100.123(`double`) * 0 = 0(`double`)